I can't fetch from a php file to javascript
I am currently trying to output data from my php file into javascript, but I get this error:

I was expecting the php file I fetched to output the ip address, but that didn't work and return 405 error.
script.js file:
fetch('./index.php', {
        method: 'post'
      }).then(response => {
         return response.text();
      }).then(response => {
         document.getElementById("status").innerHTML = response
      });

index.php file:
<?php
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];
    } elseif (!empty($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'])) {
        $ip = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];
    } else {
        $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    }

    return $ip;
?>


try using a GET request - since you aren't sending any request body anyway

Check the response header for Allow and set up your server accordingly

405 Method Not Allowed is usually what you get, when the web server thinks you are trying to make a POST request to a "static" resource. You most likely do not have properly integrated PHP into your webserver to begin with here.

What webserver are you using to serve this? Some basic ones, like the built-in one in Visual Studio Code, for example, can't run PHP and don't even accept POST requests (which is the reason you're getting a 405 Method Not Allowed error - it's saying the server doesn't allow the HTTP POST method to be used). You need to use a proper webserver such as Apache which can execute PHP and run the full HTTP protocol. Installers such as XAMPP or Laragon can get you up and running with that with a few clicks. Any beginner tutorial worth reading should show you how to set up your environment properly.

My mistake, the index.php file should be in the "assets/php/index.php" and not just "index.php", the problem was solved when I changed that. Thanks for your answers.
